# Batch file Cout math examples from txt file

Tags: batch-file

Hello I have txt file with math examples:

```
12;+;56
893;+;354
756;-;231
987;-;884
14;*;15
45;*;33
1024;/;10
120;/;30
12345;+;5667
15747;-2344
```

And I have batch file for counting. I want to display examples + resul in batch file
I have this code, but it return result 0.

```
@echo off
cls
echo Examples:
echo.
set result=0
for /f  "eol=# delims=; tokens=1,2,3" %%A in (examples.txt) do (
set result=%%A%%B%%C
echo %%A%%B%%C = %result%
)

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `set /a` to do arithmetic calculations. You'll also need `delayedepxansion` and let's use `usebackq` in order to use double quotes if the input file is in a path containing spaces.

```
@echo off & set result=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cls
echo Examples:
echo(
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-3*delims=;" %%A in ("examples.txt") do (
    set /a result=%%A%%B%%C
    echo %%A%%B%%C = !result!
)
pause
```

Check you `examples.txt` file as well as you forgot a semicolon on the last example.